# Pandas dataframe groupby and aggreagate with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way where I can group my dataframe based on specific columns and include empty value as well but only when all of the values of the specific column is empty.

Example:
I have a dataframe that look like this: 
[image]

I am trying to group the dataframe based on Name and Subject.
and my expected output looks like this:
[image]

So, if a person takes more than one subject but one of them is empty, then drop the row so when aggregating the other rows it wont be included. If a person takes only one subject and it is empty then dont drop the row

[Updated]
Original dataframe
[image]

Outcome will still be the same. It will takes the first row value if all subjects of a person is empty

[Updated] Another new dataframe

[image]

Outcome will have the same number of subjects but there will be 3 year
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposition with [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) :

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["ID", "Name", "Subject"])

m = (df.groupby(["ID", "Name"])["Subject"].transform("size").gt(1)
     & df["Subject"].isnull())

out = df.loc[~m].groupby(["ID", "Name"], as_index=False).agg(list)
```

Output :
​

```
print(out)

   ID Name          Subject    Year
0   1   CC  [Math, English]  [1, 3]
1   2   DD        [Physics]     [2]
2   3   EE      [Chemistry]     [1]
3   4   FF            [nan]     [0]
4   5   GG            [nan]     [0]
```

Comment: Hi thankss for your answer! it works. But I think I have forgetten to labelled the last second person and last person' year  to be unique. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I updated my answer, can you check it out ?